# Cant update mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I really dont know whats wrong with it, i can generate data with a similar php and another nearly identical without the $categoria = $_POST["CAT"]; and     $sql .= "SET catPERS='$categoria' "; (there is some spanish in it, ill translate if you need it)

```
<?php
// PROCESO PERSONAS UPD (ACTUALIZACION)

// CONECTAR AL SERVIDOR DE BASE DE DATOS
$conex = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

// CONTROLAR CONEXION
if (!$conex) {
    die("ATENCION!!!.. NO se pudo CONECTAR al SERVIDOR de Bae de Datos");
} // endif

// SELECCIONAR BASE DE DATOS
$selDB = mysql_select_db("database",$conex);

// CONTROLAR SELECCION DE BASE DE DATOS
if (!$selDB) {
    die("ATENCION!!!.. NO se pudo SELECCIONAR Base de Datos");
} // endif

// CAPTURAR DATOS DEL FORMULARIO
$id             = $_POST["ID"];
$nombre         = $_POST["NOM"];
$direccion      = $_POST["DIR"];
$telefono       = $_POST["TEL"];
$departamento   = $_POST["DTO"];
$categoria      = $_POST["CAT"];     

// CREAR SENTENCIA SQL PARA ACTUALIZACION
$sql  = "UPDATE Personas ";
$sql .= "SET nomPERS='$nombre', ";
$sql .= "SET dirPERS='$direccion', ";
$sql .= "SET telPERS='$telefono', ";
$sql .= "SET dtoPERS='$departamento', ";
$sql .= "SET catPERS='$categoria' ";
$sql .= "WHERE idPERS=$id";

// die($sql);

// EJECUTAR SENTENCIA SQL
mysql_query($sql,$conex); 

// CERRAR CONEXION
mysql_close($conex);

// VOLVER AUTOMATICAMENTE AL FORMULARIO DE ACTUALIZACIÓN (REDIRIGIR)
header("Location: productos.html");
?>
```

Comment: Check if there is any output `mysql_query($sql,$conex) or die(mysql_error());` and read about SQL injections and do not use mysql_ extension as it will not be supported in the future.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 3):

When updating multiple values in an update query, **you only need one** [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html) keyword and separate the other values with a comma.

Comment: @MikeBrant Had you reloaded the answer before posting, you would've seen that I deleted my comment ;) and +1 the answer.

Comment: I misread your answer Juru. You're entirely right. TBH, I have a slight case of dyslexia, which bites me in the *"you know what"* sometimes; one of those times being today lol - I +1 it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to use `mysql_` as it's currently deprecated. Furthermore, your query string is vulnerable to SQL injection. Time to step up your game, Santiago.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("update Personas set nomPERS = ?, dirPERS = ?, telPERS = ?, dtoPERS = ?, catPERS = ?, where idPERS = ?")):
    $stmt->bind_param('sssssi', $_POST['ID'], $_POST['NOM'], $_POST['DIR'], $_POST['TEL'], $_POST['DTO'], $_POST['CAT'], $id);

    if($stmt->execute()):
         $stmt->close();
         header("Location: productos.html");
    endif;
endif;
```

This is the *safe* way. It will also resolve issues with your (currently) broken SQL query.

By using prepared statements in mysqli we're avoiding SQL injection that is possible in your current code.

**Links**

1. [MySQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
2. [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
3. [Binding Parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
4. [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)